# destroy particular session Among two sessions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have maintained two sessions with different variable set to true at the time of login in my application in codeigniter. The first session is for the admin and the second is for normal users. Now what i want is when admin logs in then i have to destroy all sessions of normal user and fetch admin data.
My code is as :
for admin login
$query = $this->dbmodel->validate(); //to validate admin//
            if ($query) {

```
            // if the user's credentials validated...

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'admin_logged_in' => true


            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

for normal user

```
                $data = array(
                'useremail' => $email,
                'username' => $name,
                'logged_in' => true);

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why set 2 different sessions? why not `IF(ADMIN)` -> `set admin session to` -> **`TRUE`** -> `otherwise` -> `set admin session to` -> **`FALSE`** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set different session for admin and normal user like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('normal_user_session_data',$data); // normal user
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_login_session_data',$data); // admin
```

for unset :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('normal_user_login_session_data');// unset normal user session
$this->session->unset_userdata('admin_login_session_data'); // unset admin session
```

Comment: This would be good idea. But if normal user is already logged in in site and admin logs in dashboard, i have to destroy the whole session of that normal user and start a session of admin in site too. This is because on the link to update userdata i got already logged in user's data. So waht should i do?

Comment: then only need to unset normal user data and set admin session data

Answer (score 0):

you can use unset for delete all session stored in userdata.

```
unset($this->session->userdata);
```

Comment: Thank You all unset userdata saved my time. Thanks alot!